# error while adding a column in oracle 10 g

Tags: sql, oracle10g

i am trying to add a column validFrom to my table

this is my query

```
alter table mytable add validFrom date default getdate()  not null
```

i am getting  error like

```
ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here
```

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not have a `getdate()` function - something which can easily be found out by looking into the manual.

You need to use `SYSDATE` or `CURRENT_DATE`

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD (validFrom date DEFAULT sysdate);
```